# Prove this integral, the Dirichlet's formula

Tags: analysis, special-functions

> Show that $$\int\int_R x^{p-1}y^{q-1}dxdy  = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{p}{2})\Gamma(\frac{q}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{p}{2}+\frac{q}{2}+1)},$$
>   where R is the region bounded by the first quadrant of the circle $$x^2 +y^2=1$$

Comment: Do you know how to find the limits of integration?

Comment: no, I don't know . plz find the limits

Comment: Please show your working in future. This will help us to provide answers appropriate to your level of understanding :)

Comment: Note that one doesn't "prove" integrals, one *evaluates* them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Aim for the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and use the identity $$B(a, b)=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma (a+b)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} x^{p-1} y^{q-1} dx dy.$$

Check $\beta$ function to finish the problem.